# Can't seem to exclude node_modules from eslint

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, eslint, typescript-eslint

I've been trying to resurrect the build for an older bit of web code that's been left fallow for a while, and that involved upgrading some of the packages, including eslint. However, the build now complains about eslint errors in multiple packages in the node_modules folder.

The current relevant packages I've got in my package.json are

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.8",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.8",
"@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
"@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
"eslint": "^8.42.0",
"eslint-plugin-codeceptjs": "^1.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.1",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.14.1",
```

I've tried two approaches to excluding these folders from the eslint scan. First of all, I added an ignorePatterns line to the .eslintrc.js in the root folder. The file is at the same level as the node_modules folder. This is the syntax I've tried most recently:

```
ignorePatterns: ["**/node_modules/**"],
```

This is beneath the rules section and above the overrides section. I've tried various other versions of the ignore syntax but none of them seem to end up excluding the files.

This is the current .eslintrc.js file in full.

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true
    },
    extends: [
        "plugin:vue/essential",
        "eslint:recommended",
        "@vue/typescript/recommended",
        "@vue/prettier",
        "@vue/prettier/@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020
    },
    rules: {
        "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
        "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error"
    },
    ignorePatterns: ["**/node_modules/**"],
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ["**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)", "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"],
            env: {
                jest: true
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

I've also tried adding rows to the .eslintignore file which as the same level as .eslintrc.js in the root folder. Again, I've tried various versions of this and left them in the file. My current entry reads:

```
node_modules/
```

But I've also tried variations like preceding it with a slash, suffixing it with a ** and so on. Again, nothing I've tried leads to the build ignoring the folder.

Currently, I've got both the above changes in my build - I've not read anything about them not being used together but it's still not working. What's the correct syntax to have eslint exclude the node_modules folder, please?

Comment: I'd double-check what ESLint config files there are; it should ignore node_modules by default, IIRC. I'd also check how you're specifying which dirs/files it **should** be linting.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks - I've added the whole .eslintrc.js in case that's any help. I'm not aware of any other config specified anywhere else, like in the package.json

Comment: Unsure why the downvotes tbh. Can you run eslint with `--debug` and add the output to the question? Just to see if it's *actually* loading your config and not some other random one haha.